# What is the running time T(n) of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

> What is the running time T(n) of a program
> implementing this algorithm - What is The Total Time ?
>
> T (n) ≈ cop C(n).

```
sum = 0;
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
        sum++;
for (k=0; k<n; k++) 
    A[k] = k;
```

Comment: n^2 ______________

Comment: `O('n**2')` from nested loops

Comment: n^2 / 2 + n => O(n^2)

Comment: Please if anyone can explain the steps ? How do I know and calculate the total time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested loops

```
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
      sum++;
```

brings

```
  n           - outer loop
  (n + 1) / 2 - inner loop

  n * (n + 1) / 2 == 0.5 * (n^2 + n) == O(n^2)
```

operations. You can implement a better `O(n)` routine:

```
  sum = n > 0 ? n * (n + 1) / 2 : 0;

  for (k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    A[k] = k;
```

Comment: (n + 1) / 2 - inner loop //  Why we divide on / 2 ?

Comment: @Saffor: when `i == n` we have `n` loops; when `i == 1` we have just `1` loop; so we have `(n + 1) / 2` on average

Answer (score 1):

You reach the instruction `sum++;` `n(n+1)/2` times and the instruction `A[k]=k;` `n` times.

The total would be `T(n)=(n^2+3n)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exact analysis, it will be like the following (we need to start from inside out):

[image]

where c1, c2 are constants.